# How to place view on every 3rd index of recycler view in android?

Tags: android

I have a recycler view in which there are some string like 0,1,2,3 and so on and in the same recyclerview i want to place a view like imageview on every 3rd index. Code mentioned below is working fine but problem is that imageview starts from 0 index like sequence :- Imageview-->0,1,2--->imageview--->. Here i don't want to show image view before index 0.

code:-

```
 mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dealList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // set divider between items of list
    mList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
    int size = list.length;
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i%2==0){
            newList.add(null);
        }
        newList.add(list[i]);
    }
    adapter = new CMyAdapter(mContext, newList);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

code for Adapter:-

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> newList;
private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 0;
private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;

public CMyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.newList = list;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
        View adView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view2, parent, false);
        holder = new AdViewHolder(adView);
    } else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view1, parent, false);
        holder = new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    return holder;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (newList.get(position) == null) {
        return AD_TYPE;
    } else {
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (newList.get(position) == null) {
        AdViewHolder adViewHolder = (AdViewHolder) holder;
        adViewHolder.m_dummyImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    } else {
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        itemViewHolder.m_Text.setText(newList.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


    }
}

private class ItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    TextView m_Text;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        m_Text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDemo);
    }
}

private class AdViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    ImageView m_dummyImage;

    AdViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        m_dummyImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adImage);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

add (i!=0) in if Condition

```
if (i%2==0 && i!=0){
        newList.add(null);
    }
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i%2==0 && i!=0){
            newList.add(null);
        }
        newList.add(list[i]);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on CMyAdapter

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position%3==0) {
           //TODO
        } else {
           //TODO      
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is same by doing above methid

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 if (position%3==0 && position>0){
  AdViewHolder adViewHolder = (AdViewHolder) holder;
  adViewHolder.m_dummyImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
 } else {
  ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
  itemViewHolder.m_Text.setText(newList.get(position));
 }
}
```

Comment: please explain how your answer can solve OP's question.